# Will calling a non-virtual function on a class that has a vtable be dynamically dispatched?

Tags: c++

I assume the answer to be no and that it will be statically dispatched.  But i wanted to be sure.  I do know that this is all implementation-specific, but in general.....? Thanks.

Comment: You are correct, the answer is no, it will be statically dispatched.  The virtual dispatch mechanism is an "opt in" feature, by using the `virtual` keyword.

Comment: The vtable is implementation-specific, the observable behavior of which function is being called is not.

Comment: Even the virtual functions might be statically dispatched if the object type is known at compile time.

Comment: @BoPersson: True, even if it's the wrong type ([Adventures in undefined behavior: The premature downcast](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120831-00/?p=6713)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not virtual, it's not dynamically dispatched. Even if the class has other functions which *are* virtual, those that aren't will be bound statically.

The C++ motto is that you shouldn't pay for what you don't use. And in this case, you don't pay for dispatching a function dynamically, if you didn't specify you need to (by declaring it `virtual`).

Comment: Worth noting, that none of that is mandated by the language specification. If you want to find out, what your implementation is doing, make sure to look at your compiler's output. It's unlikely for an implementation to implement dynamic dispatch for something that can be decided at compile-time, but there are strange compilers out there.

Comment: @IInspectable - I'm sorry by your comment is a bit backwards. A non-virtual function would not be subject to dynamic dispatch, that *is* mandated. A virtual function may be resolved statically, but that is not the subject of the post.

Comment: Nothing in the language specification mandates, that non-virtual functions cannot be placed in v-tables. A compliant implementation may opt to put all class members into a v-table, and perform dynamic dispatch. I don't see how any of this is backwards. It's unlikely, and I cannot think of a reason to do so. But there are strange compilers out there, and their authors may have reason to do what may appear to be needless.

Comment: Actually, I think @IInspectable is, in a way, right.  A call to a non-virtual function must end up at the statically determined function (we all agree there) - but it *might* end up there via an indirection through the vtable.  Whether you call that dynamic dispatch is a matter of terminology.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Correct. There is nothing in the language specification that disallows dynamic dispatch, even if the target can be determined at compile time. As such, the statement *"If it's not virtual, it's not dynamically dispatched."* is wrong. It is very likely, that an implementation chooses not to spend clock cycles on something that can be determined at compile-time. But there simply is no requirement to do so, and a compliant implementation could choose to perform dynamic dispatch after all. Probably going to have to down-vote this submission, unless the wording is fixed.

Comment: @MartinBonner - [*"If the selected function is non-virtual, or if the id-expression in the class member access expression is a qualified-id, that function is called. **Otherwise**, its final overrider in the dynamic type of the object expression is called; such a call is referred to as a virtual function call."*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.call). A virtual function call and a regular function call are two *different* things that are supposed to happen. If a regaular call ends up being a virtual call, that looks to me like non-conformance.

Comment: @IInspectable - Knock yourself out. I won't be bullied to "fix" what isn't broken.

Comment: *"That function is called"* does not mandate, **how** that function is to be called. I don't know, why you believe that virtual dispatch for a *"regular function call"* were somehow non-conforming. Would there be any difference in the observable behavior?

Comment: @IInspectable What? According to what you're saying, it's all kosher if an implementation calls `Derived::foo` when you call `baseptr->foo()`, even if `foo` is not `virtual` and `Derived` has *hidden* the `Base::foo` implementation? Or are you arguing implementations may choose to add everything to a vtable but never make use of certain entries? If so, that's pointless nit-picking. Default constructing a `vector` may open a network connection and perform a Google search too, but adding that caveat to an answer is of no benefit to anyone.

Comment: @StoryTeller: "that function is called" - agreed.  The standard doesn't say that the compiler doesn't call that function via a unique offset in the vtable though. (Given that it doesn't mention vtable at all.)

Comment: @Praetorian: No, he is not saying that.  `Base::foo` would be at vtable offset 7, `Derived::foo` would be at vtable offset 43 (for example).

Comment: @Praetorian: I wasn't suggesting, that an implementation implemented an invalid v-table, or arrive at a different function than required. The nit-picking is not at all pointless, nor is it even nit-picking. StoryTeller stated as a fact, what isn't a fact. Pointing that out is called diligence.

Comment: @IInspectable - No it's called incessant pedantry.

Comment: ISO/IEC 14882 [expr.call]/1 explicitly says only that a (non-virtual) member function is called, it doesn't say its address is not determined by looking it up in  some sort of table (like a GOT) first.  Routing it through an object's virtual call dispatch table would be a perverse and retrogressive thing for an implementation to do, though, despite not being non-conformant.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb - An implementation cannot route via vtable as a vtable is specified in current implementations . It would have to make an augmented vtable, to make sure that each and every function is dispatched thorough it, and it better make sure the entry chosen would be the one determined statically. Basically it would be creating a problem for itself to solve. Not to mention it's quite easy to introduce non-conformance by accident when going that route. That's not plainly retrogressive, that's downright boneheaded.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb: What about architectures, where a virtual dispatch is no slower than a direct call? What about architectures, that do not even support direct calls? What, if virtual dispatch leads to smaller code? The point I'm trying to make is: It is perfectly legal for a compliant implementation to choose any means to produce the specified behavior. This answer states that *X* won't ever happen if *Y*, while it is perfectly legal to do *X* when *Y*. This is inaccurate, and I'm hoping for the voting system to work as intended.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Yeah, right, because it is so darn easy to not make that same mistake by accident, when determining the possibility of a static dispatch... Like your answer, that comment is voicing unfounded opinion.

Comment: @IInspectable - You know statistically speaking, the nitrogen atoms in the atmosphere could from a condensed bubble around a persons head and suffocate them. Alas such anomalies are not common, so I doubt your "hope that the voting system would work as intended" will come to fruition.

Comment: I provided reasons, why an implementation may opt to use dynamic dispatch, even if not strictly required: Real compilers for real CPU architectures. There is nothing hypothetical here. The bottom line is: Your answer is wrong. You weren't able to find anything in the language specification to back up your claims. And now you have opted to make someone else sound more wrong, just so that you don't look as wrong as you are. That doesn't change the facts, though: This answer is wrong as written. It is up to you to make use of the feedback. And it is up to me to vote, in case you don't.

Comment: Fun fact, from your [SO Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller): *"Over the past several years on SO I learned the following: The vital importance of being precise."*

Comment: @IInspectable - Here's another fun fact: you spoke of hypotethical implementions and haven't named a *single* **real** architecture. Your entire tirade here, as evident by your final ad-hominen quote of my profile, is about childish posturing at the fact I dismissed your first comment. You have no argument and no architecture to support your claim. Your voting, as evident by the condesending allusion to it before the fact, is purely vindictive. I will not be interacting with you further.